# Convert a predictor to categorical in Python

Tags: python, encoding, keras, categorical-data

Is there any function in Keras that allows me to convert a numeric/continuous predictor into categorical variable quickly? I know we do one-hot encoding but I am looking for something similar like this in R:

```
var = as.factor(var)
```

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(var)
encoded_var = encoder.transform(var)
```

and if you want one-hot encoded:

```
dummy_var = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_var)
```